# Laravel Ajax Input::all() return empty when send it via FormData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

im building an application with Laravel 4, in some point i want to add some model throught modal(Bootstrap) so i needed ajax to send my from, i have setup my route and action in controller, and then i have built the form markup with blade, i have wrote the ajax code, the request goes fine and i retrieve the inputs through Input facade, the problem here is that form has a file input, and when serialising form data with $('#formRub ').serialize(), it can't handle the file input, so i have to use FromData object and set the processData and contentType to false in the ajax request, the request sent, but i when u access to Input facade i got empty array !!

Route :

`Route::post('/add', ['as' => 'rubrique.add.post', 'uses' => 'RubriquesController@ajaxaddpost']);`

Controller :

```
class RubriquesController extends \BaseController {


public function ajaxaddpost(){
  return  dd(Input::all());
    $v = Validator::make(Input::all(), Rubrique::$rules);
    if($v->fails()){
        return Response::json([
            'fail' => true,
            'errors' => $v->errors()->toArray()
        ]);
    }
    if(Input::hasFile('image'))
        return Response::json(['success' => Input::file('image')]);

    return Response::json(['fail' => 400]);
}
```

Markup :

```
         {{ Form::open(['route' => 'rubrique.add.post', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'rubForm']) }}
                {{Form::label('name', 'Nom de la boutique :', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Entrer votre nom de boutique..'])}}

                {{Form::label('desc', 'Description :', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::textarea('desc', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter votre e-mail..', 'rows' => '3'])}}



                {{Form::label('image', 'Image :', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}
                    {{Form::file('image', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter votre e-mail..'])}}

                {{Form::label('rubrique_id', 'Rubrique Parent :', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}
                    {{ Form::rubriques(0) }}

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                {{Form::submit('Ajouter', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'sendRubrique']) }}

            </div>
        </div>
        {{Form::close()}}
```

JS:

```
        $('#rubForm').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $( this ),
                dataFrom = new FormData($form),
                url = $form.attr( "action"),
                method = $form.attr( "method" );

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: dataFrom,
                type: method,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
        });
```

Comment: Try this plugin
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: i dont want a plugin for uploading, i just need an upload in this form only, so can you help me why this won't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JavaScript should look like this:

```
$('#rubForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $( this ),
        dataFrom = $form.serialize(),
        url = $form.attr( "action"),
        method = $form.attr( "method" );

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: dataFrom,
        type: method,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

You should use `$form.serialize()` and you have to remove `contentType: false,`

Now if you put into your controller for example something like this:

```
file_put_contents("test.txt", var_export(Input::all(), true));
```

it will create file with data in it however I don't know if it will work for file input

**EDIT**

I didn't notice seralize() and file input in the question, so now, you should add name attribute to your form:

```
 {{ Form::open(['route' => 'rubrique.add.post', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'rubForm', 'name' =>'myform']) }}
```

and use the following code:

```
$('#rubForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $( this ),

        dataFrom = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("myform"));
        url = $form.attr( "action"),
        method = $form.attr( "method" );

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: dataFrom,
        type: method,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Comment: i dont think you have read my question description, i have already did that but $form.serialize doesn't work with files !!

Comment: thank you sooooo much !! you saved my life !!, but if you know why the normal selector didn't work ? what with document.forms ??

Comment: @Ilyass I don't know why you should use such syntax but as you see it works (I found it in some docs in Google)

Answer (score 3):

The key are in your ajax request.  In the controller you can do whatever you want.

```
var form = document.forms.namedItem("yourformname"); // high importance!, here you need change "yourformname" with the name of your form
var formdata = new FormData(form); // high importance!

$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json", // or html if you want...
    contentType: false, // high importance!
    url: '{{ action('yourController@postMethod') }}', // you need change it.
    data: formdata, // high importance!
    processData: false, // high importance!
    success: function (data) {

        //do thing with data....

    },
    timeout: 10000
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because is sending the array with a "data" , is the same as the jquery ajax, the `Input::all()` is showing `[data]='_token=d76as78d6as87d6a&data1=value1` etc... not as a sincronized request if you print values `Input::all` will show you a complete array, laravel handle a different way the POST requests sent by jQuery