# POST request with ajax and jquery serialize() lost values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to retrieve four values from a post request but I only get 2 of them. The form contains an id, step, name, and email but I only get the ones from the hidden inputs. And not the ones that the user fills in. I think that it might be the jquery `serialize()` but i'm not sure.

I have tried to change the inputs to hidden and then add value="something" and it works. Why doesent it work with regular text?

//result from post request:

```
[position_id] => 229
[step] => 1
[name] => 
[email] =>
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form id="referral-form" action="#" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="position_id" value="{{$position->id}}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" id="name" required/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="email" class="form-control" type="text" id="email" required />
    </div>
    <div id="legal">
        <span class="loader-button"></span>
        <div class="button submit"></div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I have a javascript method that get initiated if user clicks on `.button.submit`

```
onRef: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $("#referral-form");

    if(!$form.hasClass("ajax"))
    {
        $form.addClass("ajax");
        $form.find('.error').css('display', 'none');

        var req = $.post('/reff/ref', $form.serialize());

        req.done(function(res) {
            $form.removeClass("ajax");

            if(res.success) {
                //do somthing
            }
            else {
                methods.printErrors(res.errors, $form);

                mixpanel.track('onReferralValidationFailure', {
                    errors: res.errors,
                    positionId: exported.position.id,
                    companyId: exported.position.company_id
                });
            }
        });

        req.fail(function() {
            $form.removeClass("ajax");

            mixpanel.track('onReferralUnknownError', {
                positionId: exported.position.id,
                companyId: exported.position.company_id
            });
        });
    }
},
```

And when I try to retrieve the post data within the /reff/ref function in php I only get this data.

```
[2016-07-07 11:58:39] local.INFO: Array
(
    [position_id] => 229
    [step] => 1
    [name] => 
    [email] => 
)
```

This is the function in reff/ref:

```
 public function refer() {
    $positionId = Input::get("position_id");
    Language::setLanguageByPositionId($positionId);

    if(Input::get("step") == 1) {
        $validator = new ReferralStepOneValidator(App::make('validator'));
        $validator->with(Input::all());

        Log::info(print_r(Input::all(), true));

        if($validator->passes()) {
            $input = Input::all();


            $referral = Referral::createReferralFromInput($input);

            return Response::json(array(
                'success' => true,
                'reference' => $referral->reference,
            ));
        }
        else {
            return Response::json(array(
                'success' => false,
                'errors' => $validator->errors()->toArray(),
            ));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what's in /reff/ref?

Comment: Make sure `$form` has all the correct data and `$form.serialize()` doesn't do anything funny to them.

Comment: You can check your sent data (Chrome: developers tool, network) and verify which params are being sent in the post request.

Comment: @awl19 i have added the refer ref

Comment: The problem is in /reff/ref - I'm guessing you're using a framework I'm not familiar with, so I can't tell exactly how you're passing the variables through the JSON array, but if you do a search for "user" or "email" in /reff/ref you'll see neither one is being called or defined.

Comment: nah it's probably not. Im using Laravel 5.2

Comment: @awl19 If you look at this line Log::info(print_r(Input::all(), true)); this is what prints the array, so it finds name and email but no values for them.

Comment: You're right. I'm curious, you should give this a shot...try typing in numbers for the name and email fields. I'm wondering if it's not accepting non-numbers for some reason? If that doesn't work, try it again, but change the input type to number or hidden (like the two fields that are working) and set default values for them as well

Comment: @awl19 it worked with hidden inputs [2016-07-07 13:21:07] local.INFO: Array
(
    [position_id] => 229
    [step] => 1
    [name] => Test
    [email] => test@testing.com
)

Comment: It's possible Laravel isn't communicating well with JQuery. Try this method for posting the form: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26158884/1790315 - Look specifically at the bit that would replace $form.serialize() in your JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i can't comment yet. I am watching this issue and tried a few things. Can you put a console log before post?

```
<script>
$('#referral-form').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $("#referral-form");


    if(!$form.hasClass("ajax"))
    {
        $form.addClass("ajax");
        $form.find('.error').css('display', 'none');

        console.log($form.serialize());

        var req = $.post('/reff/ref', $form.serialize());

        req.done(function(res) {
            $form.removeClass("ajax");

            if(res.success) {
                //do somthing
            }
            else {
                methods.printErrors(res.errors, $form);

                mixpanel.track('onReferralValidationFailure', {
                    errors: res.errors,
                    positionId: exported.position.id,
                    companyId: exported.position.company_id
                });
            }
        });

        req.fail(function() {
            $form.removeClass("ajax");

            mixpanel.track('onReferralUnknownError', {
                positionId: exported.position.id,
                companyId: exported.position.company_id
            });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Also, is any chance that your js function is not executed on click event?

Comment: Thank you for yoyr answer. My Js function is executed.